# XML files has to open with microsoft XML notepad

Tags: excel, vba

I ran into an issue with using the XML files. I have a macro that searches thought the nodes inside the XML file and the macro is running fine until I restart my laptop. Every time it will go into error and I first have to open an XML file manually with Microsoft XML notepad and then it`s working again. Can I solve this without changing the default opening program on the laptop itself?

```
    Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    XMLFileName = Dir(MAIN_FOLDER & "\" & LotAppendix & "*.xml")
    oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your problem is one of just passing the filename to `Load()` - that will work if the current directory is set to MAIN_FOLDER (as for example it will be if you navigate there and manually open a file) but will fail if it's not.

The fix is to always use the full path and never rely on a specific current directory being set:

```
Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFileName = Dir(MAIN_FOLDER & "\" & LotAppendix & "*.xml")
oXMLFile.Load MAIN_FOLDER & "\" & XMLFileName
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but I don`t understand. In the end the file path is:
MAIN_FOLDER \ MAIN_FOLDER \ LotAppendix. How come it still works if the folder path is double?

Comment: `Dir()` only returns the file *name*, not the full path.